# how to fix this char array cann't stop printing

Tags: c++

[Attached  Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNvHr.png)   [Someone Please help me fix the this problem.I was using the if statement to determine the material is copper, and then I would like to use arrays to print out different type of length and material. Thank You.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtHAs.png)

```
enter code here
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
float steelbar ();
float steelrod ();
char printMenu ();
void testing(float length, float area, float stress, float price);
int main()
{
char Choice;
float result;
cout<<"\t\tWelcome to Smart Calculating System\n";
cout<<"\t\t_______________________________________\n";
Choice = printMenu();
if (Choice == 'A' || Choice == 'a')
{
result = steelbar();
}
else if (Choice == 'B' || Choice == 'b')
{
result = steelrod();
}
else 
{
printf("Invalid input!\n");
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
}
}
char printMenu ()
{
char choice;
cout<<" Please choose a type:\n";
cout<<" A/a = Steel bar  B/b = Steel rod\n";
cout<<"Answer = "<<endl;
cin>>choice;
cout<<"\n";
return choice;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float steelbar ()
{
float length, width, height, pressure, area, stress, price;
int program=1;
while(program == 1)
{
cout<<"Please enter length: "<<endl;
cin>>length;
cout<<"Please enter width: "<<endl;
cin>>width;
cout<<"Please enter height: "<<endl;
cin>>height;
cout<<"Please enter pressure: "<<endl;
cin>>pressure;
area = height * width;
stress = pressure / area;

cout<<"\nThe stress is : "<<stress<<endl;

if (stress <= 690)
{
testing(length, area, stress, price);
fflush(stdin);
getchar();

cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Do you wish to continue? (Yes=1 /No=0)\n";
cout<<"Answer = ";
cin>>program;
if (program == 1)
{
    printMenu ();
}
else (program == 0);
{
    return 0;
}
}
else if (stress > 690)
{
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Please enter stress less than 690 MPA\n";
cout<<" Do you wish to continue? (Yes=1 /No=0)\n";
cout<<"Answer = "<<endl;
system("cls");
}}
return price;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float steelrod ( )
{
float length, diameter, pressure, area, stress, price ,density, rate ;
int program;
while(program == 1)
{   cout<<"Please enter length: "<<endl;
cin>>length;
cout<<"Please enter diameter: "<<endl;
cin>>diameter;
cout<<"Please enter pressure: "<<endl;
cin>>pressure;
area = (3.14159 * diameter * diameter) / 4;
stress = pressure / area;
cout<<" The stress is : "<<stress;if (stress <= 690)
{
testing(length, area, stress,price);
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
system("cls");
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Do you wish to continue? (Yes=1 /No=0)\n";
cout<<"Answer = ";
cin>>program;
if (program == 1)
{   system("cls");
    main ();
}
else (program == 0);
{return 0;
}
}
else if (stress > 690)
{
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Please enter stress less than 690 MPA\n";
cout<<" Do you wish to continue? (Yes=1 /No=0)\n";
cout<<"Answer = "<<endl;
cin>>program;
system("cls");
}
return price;
}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void testing(float length, float area, float stress, float price)
{
const char *material[30];
int i, j;

if( stress <= 70)
{
material[i] = "Copper";
price = length * area * 10 * 1.5;
}
else if( stress >70 && stress <= 130 )
{
material[i] = "Cast iron";  
price = length * area * 15 * 1.8;
}
else if( stress >130 && stress <= 200 )
{
material[i] = "Brass";
price = length * area * 17 * 2.0;
}

else if( stress >200 && stress <= 690 )
{
material[i] = "ASTM A51";
price = length * area * 22.5 * 2.20;
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<"Material : "<<material[i];
cout<<"\nThe total price is : RM"<<price<<endl; 
}
}
```

Comment: Please post more detail

Comment: Please post releavant code , expected output and observed output, suspection (from debugging) in **text** format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your intent but... I see sime things that are very strange.

(1) in `testing()`, you define the variable `i` but you don't assign any value to it; so, when you assign

```
material[i] = "Cooper";
```

the value for `i` is undefined

(2) in `printarray()`, you definition of `material` is

```
float material[i], price;
```

where `i` is a parameter of the function (with undefined value, if received from `testing()`); this isn't standard C++ because you can't define a C-style array (but was your intention?) with a not-known at compile time dimension

(3) in `printarray()` you define `material` as a `float` array of size `i` and you don't initialize the `i` values; so `material` carry `i` undefined values; when you acess it in the following `for`

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<"Material : "<<material[i];
cout<<"\nThe total price is : RM"<<price<<endl; 
}
```

you access 3 undefined values

(4) according the image you report us, with

```
cout<<"Material : "<<material[i];
```

you print a C-style string (`char *`) with values "Cooper", some garbage (uninitialized values) and empty  string; according the code you show us, `material` should be an array of `float`. I deduce that the image you show us is generated by a different code. Please, show us the corrispondent (and complete) code

(5) sorry for my bad English

Comment: is okay..
thank for you advise.
i was show my complete code already.